# Generate correlated random numbers to a given array x - specify correlation and generate the numbers

Tags: python, numpy, correlation, covariance, mincer

Sorry I am new to python and this question might be easy but: I am generating a dataset with wages, schooling, age etc.

Problem: I created a vector for wages and now I want to draw a correlated random array with a correlation of 0.5.

I have worked with `np.random.multivariate_normal` but I don't wnat to create two new arrays, rather I wnat to have wages_array as input.

Thanks in advance